# browsing history from all signed in devices

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to access history across all signed in devices but can only get the history on the current device (in this case the desktop browser).

I created a history replacement extension and have received several bad reviews because users have expected to see all their browsing history in the extension. Chrome's history viewer displays full history from all signed in devices as it says below.

[image]

I'm currently using the Sessions API to get all devices' visits in the active sessions in combination w/ the History API to get the current device's complete history, but it's not good enough.

Did I miss something or does this functionality just not exist yet in Chrome's API?

Comment: Appears that side effects of the history api not supporting synced history are visible https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395955 ...deleting a visit via the history api when history sync is enabled means that the visit is not actually deleted because it is not 'globally' deleted from synced history.

Comment: also on chrome's history viewer, it is not actually using the history API and instead calling to `chrome.send` which is private apis. Not looking good...

Comment: You'd better create a bug report for this lack of functionality at https://crbug.com/new. Make sure that you add a clear steps-to-reproduce, plus a small sample extension that shows what happens (and what should have happened instead).

Comment: @RoyKolak - Did you get any solution to fetch browser history from all synced devices?

Answer (score 5):

> One workaround is to use google search history,
>   https://history.google.com/history/, which keeps tracks of all of your
>   searches across all devices and the pages that you have opened
>   following the searches. However it is not exactly the same.

https://superuser.com/questions/849040/show-history-from-all-devices-in-chrome

Answer (score -4):

When you're signed in to Chrome on different devices, you can choose what information will sync across them -- such as your apps, bookmarks, history, and extensions.

To learn how to customize your sync settings, select your device below:

Computer
In the top-right corner of the browser window, click the Chrome menu Chrome menu .
Select Settings.
Under "Sign in," click the button Advanced sync settings.
In the drop-down menu, select how much information you want to sync. You have two options:
Sync everything: All of the information in the checkboxes will sync.
Choose what to sync: Mark the information you want to sync with checkboxes.